# Python: unable connect with database

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2

Python 3.4 with psycopg2

I used [this guide](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Using_psycopg2_with_PostgreSQL) to set up a basic `psycopg2` connection like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import psycopg2
import sys
import pprint

def main():
    conn_string = "dbname='CIBTST' host='XX.XX.XXX.XX' port='XXXX' user='XXXXX' password='XXXX'"
    conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("My_select")
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    pprint.pprint(records)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\pi24926\Desktop\Python\doSMS.py", line 14, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Users\pi24926\Desktop\Python\doSMS.py", line 8, in main
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 164, in connect
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
psycopg2.OperationalError
```

When I try the same select statement in another client (Toad) it seems to operate correctly. Any suggestions will be great. Thank you!

EDIT: The source of problem is: PORT. If I run:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import psycopg2
import sys
import pprint

def main():
    conn_string = "dbname='CIBTST' host='XX.XX.XXX.XX' user='XXXXX' password='XXXX'"
    conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("My_select")
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    pprint.pprint(records)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Then I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\pi24926\Desktop\Python\doSMS.py", line 14, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Users\pi24926\Desktop\Python\doSMS.py", line 8, in main
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 164, in connect
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out  (0x0000274C/10060)
Is the server running on host "XXXXXXX" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I can only connect under port 1522 for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the **full, unedited error**? There should be more than just `psycopg2.OperationalError`. Also, if you want help you really need to show all the releavant info. Asserting that "My SELECT is 100% correct" is a waste of time - if you knew that for sure, you wouldn't be asking for help here. You need to clearly show any parts of a a code example that are edited/redacted and explain why... or preferably not do it in the first place.

Comment: That _does_ tell more, when combined with the exact psycopg2 version you're running. What is it? Show the output of `import psycopg2` then `psycopg2.__version__`.

Comment: Yes, just did it :) I am not sure if it adds anything. The problem must be - to me - in connection, so i wrote that select is correct (returns what i want using Toad for example).

Comment: Where is the rest of the traceback message? Normally the traceback provides a little more information than just `psycopg2.OperationalError`, e.g. when the database does not exist you might see:

    psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "ada9kd1j069f4k" does not exist

Comment: Are you able to successfully establish a connection using the postgresql client `psql`?

Comment: @mhawke I am able to do it with Toad. Should I check with psql?

Comment: @ti01878 I'm not familiar with TOAD, but yes, that should confirm that you can connect to the remote db server. Are you connecting from the same machine and using __exactly__ the same values for hostname, port etc. in your python script, especially, are you using an IP address in both TOAD and python?

Comment: OK, so it's not that your `SELECT` is necessarily correct, though it runs fine in another client (which it'd be better to have said). It's that the program fails before that point. So I ask again, exact psycopg2 version?

Comment: @Craig Ringer: It is psycopg2-2.5.3 from [link](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/). Sorry, but not sure what do you mean by 'Show the output of import psycopg2'.

Comment: Thanks. I just meant "import psycopg2 then show the version". Anyway, mine's the same, and I can see that it's dying when calling into pure C code, where it's quite possible it could just throw a bare `OperationalError` if you were hitting some case the program authors thought couldn't happen and thus didn't need a better error. At this point I think you will have to provide a *totally unedited* test case that, when run, produces the error. See what you can cut out and still get the error.

Comment: Just took a look at the psycopg2 source code. There's debug tracing support there, but it requires a recompile, so *really* not fun on Windows. Drat.

Comment: I cant connect with psql, so i guess it could be an answer. I will check it and back here.

Comment: Try using `psql` with the *exact same connection string*. You can write e.g. `psql "dbname='CIBTST' host='XX.XX.XXX.XX' port='XXXX' user='XXXXX' password='XXXX'"`. The double-quotes are important and required.

Comment: @Craig Ringer Did you mean:  conn_string = psql "dbname='CIBAKC' (...)"? It doesnt work (invalid syntax)

Comment: @ti01878 Well, there's your problem then. `psycopg2` and `libpq` use the same connection string parser. That said ... you'd usually get a useful error from psycopg2, not the weird empty one you got. In any case, without the **exact and un-edited connection string** I cannot possibly help you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with database...

It is an Oracle, so i should use cx_Oracle instead of psycopg2.